# Call Macro in PowerPoint which Name is in a Excel-Cell

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I want to Call a Macro in PowerPoint which Name is in Excel on the worksheet "Tabelle1" and the Cell "S2". The Goal is to trigger different macros by changing the cell "S2".

At the Moment, I tried it with the following Code:

```
Sub SAP()
    Dim WB As Workbook, wks As Worksheet
    Dim ex As Object
    Set ex = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set WB = ex.Workbooks.Open(FileName:="U:\Automatisierung\Auto.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)
    Set wks = WB.Worksheets("Tabelle1")

Call givePathVal
Call Text_EAP
Call F_EAP
**Call WB.wks.Range("S2").Value** 'The Goal is to call this macro from PowerPoint
Call InsertPic_EAP

End Sub
```

If I run this Code, I get the error "430".

How do I have to Change the Code, to call the macro "Kapazität", which Name is in the Excel-Cell "S2".

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the [Application.Run method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.run)

For example to run a macro in your Excel application `ex` instead of `Call WB.wks.Range("S2").Value` use the following:

```
ex.Run wks.Range("S2").Value
```

or if you need to specify the workbook name:

```
ex.Run "'Auto.xlsx'!" & wks.Range("S2").Value
```

---

Or if the macro is in PowerPoint, use:

```
Application.Run wks.Range("S2").Value
```

Comment: I tried your Code, but I get the following error "1004". I think the Problem is, that I tries to run the macro from the Excel-Workbook. The Macro "Kapazität" is in PowerPoint. 
Is there a Workaround?

Comment: @Bartek Ah it was not clear that the macro is in PowerPoint. Then use `Application.Run wks.Range("S2").Value`

Comment: Note that you should close your Excel workbook `WB.Close SaveChanges:=False` and quit your Excel application `ex.Quit` after you finished (or in case of error) otherwise they will stay open until you reboot.

Comment: @PEH: Perfect! The Code `Application.Run wks.Range("S2").Value` was the solution. Thanks.